# Import relative apps in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and have a question about app structure and imports. My project structure looks like this (from [deploydjango.com](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html)):

```
root/
     manage.py
     mysite/
         __init__.py
         urls.py
         wsgi.py
         settings/
         apps/
             __init__.py
             profile
                 __init__.py
                 models.py
                 views.py
             video
                 __init__.py
                 models.py
                 views.py
             photos
                 __init__.py
                 models.py
                 views.py
```

Basically I will have some profiles on my site, where each profile then have a number of uploaded photos and videos. So in my video model I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models
from XXXXX import Profile

class Video(models.Model):
    # more fields
    company = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='videos')
```

How do I import the Profile model for use in the Video model? Or is my structure not suitable..? What would be best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your structure is fine. Basically, python's modules are just a python file which you may import like this: `import <filename>` and you will have its functionality imported. But when you group some python files in a folder and include in that folder a file called **init**.py there you have a python package. With is a better way to manage a group of modules and it allows the dot notation in your imports. Django apps behave like packages as you may see.

If you want to import `Profile` within your `video` module then you have to do this:

```
from profile.models import Profile
```

That is, assuming that the `Profile` model is defined in your `profile` app in `models.py`. That should do.

If you want more information about python project structure [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) is a great place.